# Prevent navigating to another view if contents are unsaved

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

We have a backbone.js app that displays a number of forms to the user. What we want is very simple: if the user goes to another page without saving the filled-in form, we want to display a confirmation dialog.

In classic forms this is easy enough, just implement window.onbeforeunload (or $(window).on('beforeunload') in jQuerysh). But backbone apps only have one view, typically. I tried a bit using onHashChange, but returning false in that callback does not prevent Backbone from still going to the other view.

Pointers are appreciated. Searching the interwebs didn't find me any valid response.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the original backbone "switch view" function with your own code that checks whether a switch should be allowed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would avoid hacking around with Backbone. You could do this globally for all links by replacing the part where you would normally start `Backbone.history` with something like

```
initRouter: function () {
    Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function (ev) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        ev.preventDefault();
        if (changesAreSaved) {
            router.navigate(href, true);
        }
    });
}
```

You need of course to replace the `changesAreSaved` with something that makes sense and add whatever other login you have about handling links.

Comment: I used this one, it works just as advertised. Or actually, I used both this and a $(window).on('beforeunload') to catch both cases. I also set the two callbacks when certain routes are called (the add & edit routes), and unset them on every other route event.

Comment: What about the user navigating back to previous view with the browser back button?

Comment: @OlliM That clearly won't work here. I take it the use case is not to actually force the user to save, rather to remind him he hasn't if he navigates away by clicking on a link. If the back button is important then my solution does not solve it.

Comment: This also doesn't solve the case where the user reloads the page.  I think that onbeforeunload is necessary

Answer (score 6):

I would also hack `Backbone.history.loadUrl`, that's where loading the route callbacks happen.

```
// ALLOW PREVENTING HASH NAVIGATION

var originalFn = Backbone.history.loadUrl;

Backbone.history.loadUrl = function() {
    // I introduced an application state variable, but it can be solved in multiple ways
    if (app && app.states.isNavigationBlocked) {
        var previousFragment = Backbone.history.fragment;
        window.location.hash = '#' + previousFragment;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return originalFn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```

## Explanation:

#### 1)

Backbone listens to the **`hashchange` event** and sets `Backbone.history.checkUrl` as a callback:
https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.2/backbone.js#L1414

```
Backbone.$(window).on('hashchange', this.checkUrl);
```

#### 2)

[`Backbone.history.checkUrl`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.2/backbone.js#L1464) checks if the hash has changed and calls `Backbone.history.loadUrl`

```
checkUrl: function(e) {
  var current = this.getFragment();
  if (current === this.fragment && this.iframe) {
    current = this.getFragment(this.getHash(this.iframe));
  }
  if (current === this.fragment) return false;
  if (this.iframe) this.navigate(current);
  this.loadUrl();
},
```

#### 3)

[`Backbone.history.loadUrl`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.2/backbone.js#L1477) finds the first matching route and calls its callback:

```
loadUrl: function(fragment) {
  fragment = this.fragment = this.getFragment(fragment);
  return _.any(this.handlers, function(handler) {
    if (handler.route.test(fragment)) {
      handler.callback(fragment);
      return true;
    }
  });
},
```

**Useful note:**

`Backbone.history.fragment` stores the current hash, it's set in `Backbone.history.loadUrl`, so we can access it AFTER the `hashchange` event but BEFORE the router callbacks do their job.

Comment: I tried adding a confirm dialog for the case when the navigation is blocked but it loadUrl seems to pop up multiples times, sometimes 2, sometimes 3. Do you know why that would happen?

Answer (score 5):

I think you could hack Backbone.history.loadUrl ( http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-137 ). I did a quick test, this code does a check every time you change pages. You'll want to add code to activate the check only when there is actually a reason for it.

```
var goingBack = false;
function doCheck() {
  // TODO: add code that checks the app state that we have unsaved data
  return goingBack || window.confirm("Are you sure you want to change pages?");
}

var oldLoad = Backbone.History.prototype.loadUrl;
Backbone.History.prototype.loadUrl = function() {
  if(doCheck()) {
    return oldLoad.apply(this, arguments);
  } else {
    // change hash back
    goingBack = true;
    history.back();
    goingBack = false;
    return true;
  }
}
```

You'll have to handle window.onbeforeunload as well, because the user might still leave the page entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 1.2.0 you can override method `Router.execute` and return `false` to cancel routing, like this:

```
execute: function(callback, args, name) {
    if (!changesAreSaved) {
        // tip: .confirm returns false if "cancel" pressed
        return window.confirm("You sure have some unsaved "
          + "work here, you want to abandon it?");
    }

    // this is the default part of "execute" - running the router action
    if (callback)
        callback.apply(this, args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been dealing with this issue for a little while, and I've come up with a solution. I based my solution off [this](https://paydirtapp.com/blog/backbone-in-practice-dirty-object-handling/) example.

The idea is to override the `navigate` method, and use `jQuery` `deferred` objects to wait to the appropriate time to navigate. In my case, if a user tried to navigate from my view that was dirty, a dialog needed to show that asked the user if:

1) Save the changes, then navigate
2) Don't save the changes, and navigate
3) Cancel the navigation and remain on the existing page

Below is my code for the navigate method in the `Router`:

```
navigate: function(fragment, trigger) {
    var answer,
          _this = this;

    answer = $.Deferred();
    answer.promise().then(function() {
        return Backbone.Router.prototype.navigate(fragment, trigger);
    });

    if(fragment !== undefined){     
        var splitRoute = fragment.split('/');
        app.currentPatronSection = splitRoute[splitRoute.length - 1];
    }

    if (app.recordChanged) {
        this.showConfirm(function(ans){
            // Clear out the currentView
            app.currentView = undefined;
            answer.resolve();
        }, function(){

        });
        return answer.promise();
    } else {
        return answer.resolve();
    }
    return Backbone.Router.prototype.navigate(fragment, trigger);

},
```

The `showConfirm` method presents the dialog with the three options I listed above. Based on the user's choice, I save the form, then resolve the answer to navigate, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting multiple calls to `loadUrl` per reroute using [Dénes's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535463/317135), so I decided to try this method, which worked for me.

```
/**
 * Monkey patches Backbone to prevent a reroute under certain conditions.
 *
 * Solution inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535463/317135
 *
 * @param Backbone {Backbone}
 *   Backbone 1.0.0 reference
 * @param disallowRouting {function(): boolean}
 *   Function returning `true` when routing should be disallowed.
 */
export default function permitRouteWhen(Backbone, permitRouting) {
  if (Backbone.VERSION !== '1.0.0') {
    console.error(
      `WARNING: Expected to be hacking Backbone version 1.0.0, but got
      ${Backbone.VERSION} - this could fail.`
    );
  }

  const { checkUrl } = Backbone.history;

  Backbone.history.checkUrl = function(event) {
    if (!permitRouting()) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
    return checkUrl.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
import permitRouteWhen from './backbone-permit-route-hack';
permitRouteWhen(window.Backbone, () => confirm('you wanna route?'));
```