# How to prevent routing in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-routing

When I click 'Cancel' from First page - it's ok. But 'Cancel' doesn't work when I
move to 'Second page'. In this case router redirects application to "" route.
I need to prevent this redirection.

"Cancel" - hide links, "Second page" - move to Second page

```
<script type="text/html" id="template">
    <a href="#" class="cancel">Cancel</a>
    <a href="#second">Second page</a>
</script>

<div id="container"></div>    

<script>
var View = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: $('#template').html(),

    events: {
        "click .cancel": "cancel"
    },

    cancel: function () {
        this.$el.hide();
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template);
        return this;
    }
});

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "": "first",
        "second": "second"
    },
```

Create view and replace container's html

```
    links: function () {
        var view = new View;
        $('#container').html(view.render().el);
    },

    second: function () {
        this.links();
        $('#container').prepend("<h1>Second page</h1>");
    },

    first: function () {
        this.links();
        $('#container').prepend("<h1>First page</h1>");
    }

});

$(document).ready(function () {
    app = new AppRouter;
    Backbone.history.start();
});
</script>
```

Comment: just e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should return false from the cancel handler to prevent navigation to `#`:

```
cancel: function (e) {
        this.$el.hide();
        return false;
    },
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/ says:

> Returning false from an event handler will automatically call
>   event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault().

Comment: And what if this does not work? At the beginning of my function I have already e.preventDefault(); but the router is still triggered

Comment: I found out why it did not work. It was because my view did not have a el defined. example: var view = Backbone.View.extend({el: $("#anElement"), etc..});

Comment: @SKuijers: BB 0.99: "Properties like `tagName`, `el`, and `events` may also be defined as a function, if you want to wait to define them until runtime." if it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also solve blocking hash havigation in a reusable way like **in this answer**:

**[Prevent navigating to another view if contents are unsaved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872988/prevent-navigating-to-another-view-if-contents-are-unsaved/24535463#24535463)**

This solution prevents Backbone router callbacks from firing, and though it can only run AFTER the hash has changed, this function sets the previous hash fragment back so it can't be noticed

---

Also, **for this exeact problem**, you can simply change from

```
<a href="#">...</a>
```

To

```
<a>...</a>
```

it will act as a normal HTML anchor tag (e.g. cursor is set to `pointer`) but won't navigate anywhere